# Load Balance/High availability for 2 Apache web server with multiple name based virtualhosts

Tags: apache, apache2.4

I have two apache 2.4 web server. duplicate web servers running the same application and same web page. I am planning to have a load balancer and make my website highly available. Been looking for a way on the internet but with no luck. please refer to the image for my setup.

thank you in advance

[image: Planned setup]

Comment: Welcome to SO, but you might get better answers at sister site ServerFault.com.

Comment: thank you @DaveS . will post the same question on ServerFault